# Data Loader won't open (Windows 11 pro)

Tags: data-loader, salesforcedx-cli

I have installed Zulu v18.0.2.1, even have set the JAVA HOME.

and also installed Data Loader v55

I open Data Loader using the shortcut created during installation.

After few seconds command prompt flashes and disappears and nothing happens afterwards.

Any help would be appreciated.

> PS: Unable to upload screenshots here due to server error

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly check if you have followed the steps given in this : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_install_windows.htm

Comment: Did you try to use the dataloader-55.0.0-uber.jar file by double clicking it or run using java commands ? This file is in the main folder level.

Comment: @PriyaRanjan I followed the instruction from the site you mentioned but still facing the same problem.

Comment: @SLmanI tried but it's not opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to solve after installed latest version from [azul zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk) and followed the what written in documentation of.